# Al buscar el valor en el array con el console.log de más abajo en la consola sale sin definir y no sé como solucionarlo

Tags: javascript, array, undefined

Según yo esto debiera salir bien, pero no! resulta que al buscar el valor en el array con el console.log de más abajo en la consola sale sin definir y no sé como solucionarlo y tampoco porqué pasa, si alguien fuese tan amable de explicarme por favor :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        class Point {
            contructor({x, y, control = false})  {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.control = control;
            }
        }
        const points = [  
          new Point({ x: 200, y: 540}),
          new Point({ x: 400, y: 300, control: true}),
          new Point({ x: 880, y: 540})
        ]

        console.log(points[0].x)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estas intentando acceder a la `x` de la posición `0` al hacer `console.log(points[0].x)` pero si te das cuenta el primer *Point* que agregas es un objeto vacio **`new Point({}),`** por lo mismo éste no tiene una **`x`** a diferencia del segunto y tercero que si tienen esa `x`: `new Point({ x: 400, y: 300, control: true}),  new Point({ x: 880, y: 540})`. ;)

Comment: disculpa amigo, me falto escribir esa parte, ahora ya la agregue, y si aún así sigue sin definir

Answer (score 0):

debería ser `constructor` y no `contructor`, lo tienes mal escrito:

```js
class Point {
  constructor({ x, y, control = false }) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.control = control;
  }
}
const points = [
  new Point({ x: 200, y: 540 }),
  new Point({ x: 400, y: 300, control: true }),
  new Point({ x: 880, y: 540 })
]

console.log(points[0].x)
```

Comment: ooh muchas gracias bro, saludos

Comment: Recuerda verificar la respuesta marcándole al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

en vez de usar una clase podrías usar un array de objetos

```
let points = [  
          { x: 200, y: 540},
          { x: 400, y: 300, control: true},
          { x: 880, y: 540}
        ];
        
console.log(points[0].x)
console.log(points[1].control)
console.log(points[2].y)
```